# How to implement routing when I need swipeable view inside another view with Ionic Framework?

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, ionic-view

How can I implement  [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) when I make a swipeable view inside another view with [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/)?

I need to make a calendar view, which will contain 3 parts:

1. Navigation bar (**unchangeable**)
2. Day details bar under the navigation bar **it should not move** while I swipe list (3) and it should display current day/date
3. **Scrollable/Swipeable** list of time slots available for selected day, this list **should be swipeable** back and forth to next/previous day and **scrollable**.

This is how I imagine myself how it should be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've done it much more simpler by using [ion-slide-box](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/) to which I dynamically adding slides as explained here: [How to insert data dynamically to ion-slide-box Angularjs Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864174/how-to-insert-data-dynamically-to-ion-slide-box-angularjs-ionic).

Anyway, if somebody has another idea how can it be implemented please comment or post your answer, it's good to have few another solutions in a toolbox.